# Getting an error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I am getting this error

> You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type.

This is the code:

```
</asp:GridView>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/videogames.accdb" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Table1] WHERE [ID] = ?" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ( ID,Name, ScreenName, Age, Game, YearsPlaying) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table1] SET [Name] = ?, [ScreenName] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Game] = ?, [YearsPlaying] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ScreenName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Age" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Game" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="YearsPlaying" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ScreenName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Age" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Game" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="YearsPlaying" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

I've been over this and I can not get it to work right. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

When I tried to delete the insert parameters with the Id it comes back with a different error.

Comment: Does that ID field happen to be an autoincrement field in your Access database?  Meaning your INSERT will fail if you include it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `ID` `InsertParameter`:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
```

Change your `InsertCommand`:

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] (Name, ScreenName, Age, Game, YearsPlaying) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?)"
```

[Solution to the “You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type.” Exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jongallant/archive/2009/05/02/solution-to-the-you-tried-to-assign-the-null-value-to-a-variable-that-is-not-a-variant-data-type-exception.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It might be because in the insert you have the ID while it could be an Autonumeric in the database. Try removing it from the Insert Command. Good luck!

Comment: That was my case. Thank you